# How To Receive data from website using JSON for android?

Tags: java, android, json

I created a class for my android application that connects to mysql database using json.. note that the php code getNews.php is tested and it responds with the required data in json format properly. And note that i only want to get an array containing the data with this class ArrayReceiver.java ... it isn't working though... can anyone check the code please.

ArrayReceiver.java

```
 package com.example.batoul.uptodate4;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayReceiver extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    List<Article> a=new ArrayList<Article>();
    String url="192.168.11.8/utd/getNews.php";

    Boolean error = false;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Boolean success = false;
    String msg = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    public List<Article> getA() {
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        publishProgress(2);
        //  agendaArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        try {



            //        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notActivated", "false"));


            ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
            String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(url,
                    ServiceHandler.POST, params);

            //  Log.e("aaa ", "> " + ServiceHandler.url);
            //  Log.d("Create Response: ", "> " + json);

            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    if (jsonObj != null) {
                        //int catObj22 = jsonObj.getInt("success");

                        //  if (catObj22 == 1) {
                        JSONArray titles = jsonObj.getJSONArray("title");


                        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length(); i++) {
                            String catObj = (String) titles.get(i);



                            Article obj = new Article(0,"");
                            obj.setTitle(catObj);


                            a.add(obj);

                        }

                        success = true;
                    } else {
                        success = false;
                    }
                    // }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error = true;
            return null;
        }
        Log.e("aaa ", " success");

        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
//            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
//                pDialog.dismiss();
//            }
        //    Toast.makeText(TravelsActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (success) {

            //   for (int i = 0; i < travelsArr.size(); i++) {
            //     new getPic().execute("" + i);
            // }
            //ListAdapterClass adapter = new ListAdapterClass( ArticleArr,view.getContext());
            //SubjectListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


    }
}
```

ServiceHandler.java

```
package com.example.batoul.uptodate4;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class ServiceHandler {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;
    public static String url ,u;

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }
    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);

    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));
                }
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    this.url =url +"?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(this.url);


                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            response = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

getNews.php :

```
<?php
$response = array();
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'utd1_db');
 $query = " SELECT * FROM `article`";// need change
$result = $db->query($query);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$title = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($title, $row["title"]);// need change
 }
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["title"] = $title;
 echo json_encode($response);
} else {
 $response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Nothing found";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show that your PHP site actually returns JSON

Comment: @cricket_007 this is getNews.php : `<?php
$response = array();
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'utd1_db');
 $query = " SELECT * FROM `article`";// need change
$result = $db->query($query);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$title = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($title, $row["title"]);// need change
 }
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["title"] = $title;
 echo json_encode($response);
} else {
 $response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Nothing found";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>`

Comment: Thanks. But not what I was asking. 1) Your Java code **requires** `http://` 2) Are there errors in the Logcat you are ignoring? 3) Does http://192.168.11.8/utd/getNews.php actually return JSON?  And if you are using JSON, then Retrofit would be a better library than Apache HTTP + AsyncTasks

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you so much, but it seemed that i was calling `getA()` before the `doInBackgroud()` thread was executed.. i solved it with `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3)` .. Still new to this field to recognize such problem faster.. thank you